# First time open my app, request data and save them

Tags: android

I am making an application.
I want the first time the user opens my application, display an initial screen for entering the Name, Email and Phone Number,
Then, store the input data in the memory of the mobile phone.

I want this screen appears only the first time the user opens the application, because in my application always the same Name, Email and Phone will be used.

How I can do it?

Comment: you can by declare local sqlite database or simply by using SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Its like login screen I guess...use sharedpreferences ...just google it !!!

Answer (score 2):

For only first time view either you can either use shared preference or database.

Once user enter the values store all the values in shared preference and set one flag true in shared preference, when again next time user open the application check the flag if it is true then move to next screen either open the screen for entering name, email and phone number

**Setting value in shared preference**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "test");
 editor.putInt("id", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve from Shared Preference**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name");//"No name" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
```